# pyqt: receive signal when widget becomes visible/hidden

Tags: qt, pyqt, signals

I have noticed there is no signal/event for when a QWidget becomes visible/invisible. Is there anything else I can hook to get roughly the same thing (except polling isVisible())?

I want to turn of some data fetching if the widget that displays the data is not visible.

Comment: Note that while the QWidget base class does not have a signal for this, you will find there is one for some other classes.  QWindow has [visibleChanged](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwindow.html#visible-prop) for instance...while QDockWidget has the oddly-slightly-different-name [visibilityChanged](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qdockwidget.html#visibilityChanged).

Comment: @HostileFork I guess QWindow uses visibleChanged for the signal that corresponds to `isVisible()` state-changes, because it _also_ has a QWindow::visibilityChanged that's tied to its (unrelated) [`visibility`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwindow.html#visibility-prop) property. QWindow::visibility was introduced in QT 5.1, QDockWidget::visibilityChanged dates back to Qt 4.3. Guess they regretted not naming it visibleChanged from the start. (Whereas **MY** regret would be that `visible` and `visibility` now mean two different things in the same class.)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

One solution is, you can override `QWidget::showEvent()` and `QWidget::hideEvent()` function in your widget ([documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#showEvent)). And then `emit` you custom `signal` and catch in a `slot` in the respective object. For example..

```
void MyWidget::hideEvent(QHideEvent *)
{
    // 'false' means hidden..
    emit widgetVisibilityChanged(false);
}

void MyWidget::showEvent(QShowEvent *)
{
    // 'true' means visible..
    emit widgetVisibilityChanged(true);
}
```

Now if you cannot override your widget, you can also receive above events in its parent widget using `QObject::installEventFilter ( QObject * filterObj )` and `QObject::eventFilter ( QObject * watched, QEvent * event )` combination ([documentation and example](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qobject.html#installEventFilter)).